# Differences with API's when trying to pull data

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am having difficulty with a pulling some data from an API for a school project using Jquery.

If I use the following coinmaketcap API I get the following response

> https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/

```
[
{
    "id": "bitcoin", 
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "rank": "1", 
    "price_usd": "8854.92", 
    "price_btc": "1.0", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "6759730000.0", 
    "market_cap_usd": "150480289107", 
    "available_supply": "16993975.0", 
    "total_supply": "16993975.0", 
    "max_supply": "21000000.0", 
    "percent_change_1h": "-0.13", 
    "percent_change_24h": "0.12", 
    "percent_change_7d": "8.3", 
    "last_updated": "1524459272"
}
]
```

I get am able to get the symbol for Bitcoin and place it into a variable by using this code

```
> $.getJSON('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/btc/',
> function(data){                   
>               var symbol   = (data[0].symbol)
>      })
```

Once I have it I can place it in a div.

However when I use cryptocompare API I don't get anything back

> https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/coin/generalinfo?fsyms=BTC,&tsym=USD

```
 $.getJSON('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/coin/generalinfo?fsyms=BTC&tsym=USD', function(data){
                    var symbol     = (data[0].Internal)
                           });
```

This is the response -

```
{
"Message": "Success",
"Type": 100,
"Data": [
    {
        "CoinInfo": {
            "Id": "1182",
            "Name": "BTC",
            "FullName": "Bitcoin",
            "Internal": "BTC",
            "ImageUrl": "/media/19633/btc.png",
            "Url": "/coins/btc/overview",
            "Algorithm": "SHA256",
            "ProofType": "PoW",
            "NetHashesPerSecond": 27483320229.3688,
            "BlockNumber": 518932,
            "BlockTime": 600,
            "BlockReward": 12.5,
            "Type": 1,
            "DocumentType": "Webpagecoinp"
        },
        "ConversionInfo": {
            "Conversion": "direct",
            "ConversionSymbol": "",
            "CurrencyFrom": "BTC",
            "CurrencyTo": "USD",
            "Market": "CCCAGG",
            "Supply": 16986575,
            "TotalVolume24H": 380849.0498955779,
            "SubBase": "5~",
            "SubsNeeded": [
                "5~CCCAGG~BTC~USD"
            ],
            "RAW": [
                "5~CCCAGG~BTC~USD~4~8875.23~1524460635~0.00477012~42.152119404000004~231254719~10820.885574747872~96327075.76938197~66326.58563159907~593473019.8524572~8823.46~8917.05~8804.2~8864.31~9065~8780.91~Bitfinex~7ffe9"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

Why is the second piece of code not working? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second API is returning an object (in JSON format), not an array - see how the first character is `{` and how it has keys and values? You need to access the appropriate property to get the value you want. `[0]` notation indicates you're trying to access the first element of the array, but the outer object is not an array in this situation.

```
$.getJSON('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/coin/generalinfo?fsyms=BTC&tsym=USD',
  function(data){
    var symbol = data.Data[0].CoinInfo.Internal;
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

In both the cases, we are getting data in **different form**. So, To get the 'BTC' in variable .

for 1st case -> symbol = **data[0] ['symbol']**

for 2nd case -> symbol = **data['Data'][0]['CoinInfo']['Internal']**

one is an [*array of JSON*] while other is an [*object having key 'Data' with array value*].